# Prove that if $ 0<|z|<\frac{R^2}{M+R}$ then $|f'(z)|\ne0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Define $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}z^2+\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{n}z^n$, $f(z)$ is analytic in $\{z:|z|<R\}$, and $|f'(z)|<M$. Prove $\forall z\in\{z:0<|z|<\dfrac{R^2}{M+R}\},f'(z)\ne0$.

*Hint:* $\left|\dfrac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}\right|\le\dfrac{\max_{|z|\le\rho}|f(z)|}{\rho^n}$

I'm confused at the limitation $\dfrac{R^2}{M+R}$.

Any assistance will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
 f'(z) = z + \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n+1} z^{n}
$$
and Cauchy's integral formula, applied to $f'$, gives
$$ 
|a_{n+1}| \le \frac{M}{R^n} \, .
$$
It follows that for $0 < |z| < R$
$$
\left|\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n+1} z^{n} \right| 
\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{M}{R^n} |z|^{n} = \frac{M |z|^2}{R(R-|z|)} 
$$
and therefore (using the reverse triangle inequality)
$$
 |f'(z)| \ge |z|^2  - \frac{M |z|^2}{R(R-|z|)}
= |z| \frac{R^2 - (M+R)|z|}{R(R-|z|)} \, .
$$
In particular, $|f'(z)| > 0$ if $0 < |z| < R^2/(M+R)$.